# Labels appearing in wrong location

Tags: iphone, uilabel, ios6, xib

I've added a number of UILabels to the xib of my ViewController. Some are static and some I have connected to data. For instance, I have an address field that updates depending on the input. Right next to it, though is another label that simply reads "Address:".

Here's the weird part:
Halfway through adding labels, the labels that I added outlets to all started jumping halfway up the screen when I would build and run the program. In addition, those that didn't jump (which included the first 3 outleted labels) up the screen were pushed down as if to make room for the misplaced labels. If I add new labels, they stay put, but if I outlet them, they jump up with the rest...

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Could you please be more clearer ... cudnt figure out the jump part ...

Comment: Very weird problem you have here...  Perhaps it has something to do with the way you are instantiating the outlets?  If you call initWithFrame in the viewDidLoad method, you might have a problem.

Comment: If you are adding UINavigationBar/ UITabbar dynamically there this issue happens \

Answer (score 0):

You need to set autoResizingMark.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not easier to understand but what I can say based on my understanding is...either the superview for these labels is setting layout for its subviews or...better to set the autoResizingMask to NONE in the xib itself.

Hope it helps.